# Highmaps: putting border around a category of area

Tags: highmaps

I am using higmaps to show category of data like this:

```
HighChart Code:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/category-map/

But I want to be able to show border around a category of areas, that will demarcate a set of areas from other. I do not want border around each state.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

what you are after might be acquired by passing `borderWidth: 0` to the elements in a `series`. See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qebbysub/).